# Codeigniter Database Error 1366

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I recently moved a working CI application to a new server (AWS/Ubuntu).  This new server is running PHP 7 instead of PHP 5.4 installed before. MySQL is newer too and changed mysql to mysqli. CodeIgniter is still 2.x (planning to upgrade to 3.x in the upcoming weeks).

Managed to solve some .htaccess and routing issues but now I'm getting a database error:

```
A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 1366

Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'propertyDateEffect' at row 1
```

Since this was already working before first thing I did was checking server settings. I noticed sql_mode was "STRICT" so I modified my.cnf and it now looks like: `IGNORE_SPACE,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,TRADITIONAL,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION` with `TRADITIONAL` instead of `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES`.  This however, after a mysql restart, didn't fixed the error.

What else could it be?

Comment: `Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'propertyDateEffect' at row 1` post your query

Comment: Thank you Abdulla but this query should accept empty fields.  Has been able to handle this but now is not.  That's why I'm going for a php.ini/.htaccess/server setting kind of solution.

Comment: I need query to go more on this... so add or hope you can solve it alone

Comment: Can you try setting the sql_mode to '', just to test if it's the mode. SET GLOBAL sql_mode = '';

Comment: Thank you @JeffreyHitosis .  I just did and then checked (mysqld --verbose --help) and still have sql-mode =                                                      IGNORE_SPACE,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,STRICT_ALL_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,TRADITIONAL,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION.  I created ~/.my.cnf and put sql_mode='' there which is supposed to be the lastest location and should overwrite all previous config settings.  Who might be overwriting this?

Comment: SET GLOBAL sql_mode = ''; sets at runtime, when you run this, did you encounter the same issue?Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'propertyDateEffect'

Comment: @JeffreyHitosis I ended up adding $this->db->query("SET SESSION sql_mode=''"); to every model where an insert or update is required.  This solved the issue for now but I still don't know where is my.cnf being overwritten.  Anyway, this is just for now as I'll soon change these models to work with STRICT mode.